# HQL unexpected token "(" subquery select

Tags: sql, subquery, syntax-error, hql, union

I have this query. Translate it from my sql query to hql. I have this error 
"unexpected token: ( near line 2, column"

```
String query = "SELECT MAX(number)\n" +
        "  FROM (SELECT number FROM EmployeeTripCard \n" +
        "        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM issueDate) = '2015'\n" +
        "        UNION ALL\n" +
        "        SELECT trip_card_number FROM PostgraduateTripCard\n" +
        "        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM issueDate) = '2015'\n" +
        "        UNION ALL\n" +
        "        SELECT trip_card_number FROM StudentTripCard \n" +
        "        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM issueDate) = '2015'\n" +
        "        )";




Integer result = (Integer) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).uniqueResult();
```

I don't underastand what'w wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad Vytsalo, didnt look at the databse tag.
HQL subqueries is not supported on from clauses

Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses:[Hibernate Query Language](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries)